# Positioning strings with echo, CMD, Script in Windows MSDOS

Tags: cmd, output, echo, positioning

How I can to organize my output, showing my results like  rows and columns? Example a:

```
DIR output: C:\Folder\*.*
Field1      Date       Time     Size
MidInf      2014/11/22 15:23    7664
FewInf      2014/11/22 15:23     548
Empty       2014/11/22 15:09       0
Someinf     2014/11/22 15:23     683
Empty       2014/11/22 15:09       0
Empty       2014/11/22 15:09       0
MidInf      2014/11/22 15:23    7729
FewInf      2014/11/22 15:23      65
```

Example now is with dir, but I wat to show other type information...

Other example:

```
C:\user\binder>netstat -nao | find /i "37"
  TCP    192.168.97.100:53377   23.7.112.60:443        ESTABLISHED     3260
  UDP    0.0.0.0:3702           *:*                                    1092
  UDP    0.0.0.0:3702           *:*                                    1828
  UDP    0.0.0.0:3702           *:*                                    1828
  UDP    0.0.0.0:3702           *:*                                    1092
  UDP    192.168.97.100:137     *:*                                    4
  UDP    [::]:3702              *:*                                    1828
  UDP    [::]:3702              *:*                                    1092
  UDP    [::]:3702              *:*                                    1092
  UDP    [::]:3702              *:*                                    1828

C:\user\binder>
```

Is possible?

**EDIT:**

for Windows only CMD or DOS

Comment: What system is this? What do you mean by "organize in rows and columns"? What are these commands you are running output currently, what do you want them to look like after the change?

Comment: @JNevill it is unix/linux using bash that is all that is important about it and he means how when you run the `ls` command for example the output is outputted in a nice format so basically how can he do that? but now it looks like with a closer look is he using windows, that is confusing now.

Comment: I'm still not following. The tag is `bash` and yet the commands and outputs are Windows command prompt. Furthermore the outputs shown as examples are exactly how Windows outputs the results of these commands. What is it that OP wants these outputs to look like instead?

Comment: @JNevill yes you were right this is not bash, but whatever the scripting language is built into DOS/Windows.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using unix/linux with bash then the simplest way to output information in columns would be to pipe the information to the bash command 'column'. If for example you had a text file containing a list of things that you wanted to print out your command would be:

```
more foobar.txt | column
```

I often use 'column' with the grep command as well.

```
ls | grep "foobar" | column
```

This will print in a nice columnized fashion all filenames containing "foobar" in your current directory.

For more information about the column command type 'man column' into your terminal.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
CALL :FORMAT Field1 11 DATE 10 TIME 5 Size 7
FOR %%a IN (*.*) DO FOR /f "tokens=1,2" %%b IN ("%%~ta") DO CALL :FORMAT %%~nxa 11 %%b 10 %%c 5 %%~za -7

GOTO :EOF
:: Format parameter-pairs by right-pad/left-pad
:FORMAT
SET "spaces=                                                                     "
SET "line="
:formloop
SET column=%2
IF NOT DEFINED column ECHO(%line:~0,-1%&GOTO :EOF
SET column=%~1
IF %2 gtr 0 (SET "column=%column%%spaces%") ELSE (SET "column=%spaces%%column%")
IF %2 gtr 0 (CALL SET "line=%%line%%%%column:~0,%2%% ") ELSE (CALL SET "line=%%line%%%%column:~%2%% ")
shift&SHIFT
GOTO formloop
```

Here's a demo which should be fairly obvious. It shows sensitivity to the usual suspects; set the column-width of the elephant required negative to pad-left, positive to pad-right. I've assumed a space between each column. Marshalling the data for the report body depends on the particulars of the required report. Note that `""` should produce a blank column.